# about the use of id and class: should the ids be always unique in a page?

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails

My application offers the opportunity to users to join events.
In my events index page, I iterate through all the events and show them wrapping each one in a `li` tag. The user can join an event by clicking on the following button:

```
<%= form_for(current_user.attendances.build) do |f| %>
  <div><%= f.hidden_field :event_id, value: event.id %></div>
  <%= f.submit "Join the event", class: "btn btn-primary" %>
  <%= f.label :car, class: "checkbox inline checkbox-car" do %>
    <%= f.check_box :car %>
    <span> I want to share my car </span>
  <% end %>
<% end %>
```

The html corresponding to the chekbox is:

```
<input id="attendance_car" type="checkbox" value="1" name="attendance[car]">
```

The problem is the `id` assigned automatically to the input tag, `attendance_car`: each event has the same id. Wouldn't this break the rule that the id value must be unique within the HTML document? 
I wonder what is the consequence of using in the event partial `ids` in place of `classes`, as I did by mistake with some tags: `ids` would not be unique, but I noticed the application would work.

Answer (score 2):

"Should the id be always unique in a page?" Yes, of course, any DOM element should have a unique id (if provided with one). See [w3c](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_global_id.asp) for reference on id attribute.

Why don't you simply add a number to your ids to make them unique?

Answer (score 0):

Modern browsers support multiple elements having same ID. This is no valid html and may affect google rankings. If you must have this by side effects of html helpers generating tags, don't bother, since nothing will be broken, unless you are using things like getElementById.

Comment: What does it mean: "Modern browsers support multiple elements having same ID."?

Comment: @jvillian not sure about the browser compatibility list, I remember its throwing firewall warnings on IE7.